# Migration from Visual Studio to NetBeans or some other IDE

Tags: c#, java, visual-studio, netbeans

I've done a lot of programs in C# using Visual Studio. I know that C# is terrible for games (it becomes slower as more objects are on screen), and I've heard that Java is better for games, so I decided to try re-doing a board game in Java, using the NetBeans 7.0.1

I've done some basic things in the past, and by basic, I mean Java programs where the user can move a shark around or something.

But I've noticed that most of my Java programs were hard coded. If I wanted a window (a Frame), I'd have to type it in, set the size, blah blah blah. I've gotten used to the drag, drop, edit of Visual Studio, and while I am aware of (and trying to use) the drag and drop component functionality of NetBeans, I'm still having a hard time.

For instance, when creating a Java *Desktop* Application (from NetBeans), it automatically provides me with a Panel, which I believe would serve as the main "Window". But I can't edit it, or at least, can't find the properties that I need to edit (size, start position, no min, max, close buttons, background images, etc.). My attempts at coding usually fails, because apparently, the Panel automatically generates code that I can't edit.

I don't want to hard code everything, since I can imagine it would be a nightmare (the board is an 8 x 9 square one. Every square is a button).

So, how should I begin? I tried doing both Java Application and Java Desktop Application (don't know the difference between the two), but I still fall to the same problem; I can't edit anything, at least not in the quick and easy way I'm used to in Visual Studio?

If this impossible, then I'm afraid I'll have to stick to C#. A friend told me XNA is okay for games (said friend also told me XNA is overkill for a relatively simple board game).

Comment: "I heard" is a terrible way to make decisions. C# and Java are each very capable for creating simple games.

Comment: Pick up a Java book and a Netbeans manual and start reading. Java visual editors for Swing are not as powerful as in MS Visual Studio, so you sometimes needs to define the properties hardcoded like `panel.setSize(100, 100))`.

Comment: You're implementing a board game and you have memory problems? I think it's your design and implementation rather than the language or framework that's the issue here.

Comment: "it becomes slower as more objects are on screen" - true for all languages and platforms, not just C#.

Comment: Ofcourse we all know that C# is terrible for games and java is terrible for desktop applications ***sarcasme***

Comment: Java and C# are capable of 2D table-like games in nowadays machines. Try using OpenGL in Java if you need lots of performance (JOGL is a Java-OpenGL binding).

Comment: @David Oliván Ubieto, ouch. That's what I was afraid of. Anyway, thanks for the answer. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @zack_falcon - I have seen massive games, with thousands of objects, written in C#. There is terraria amoung others.  It sounds like your friend gave you bad advice saying that XNA was overkill for a board game.

Comment: @Ramhound I did an XNA tutorial for making a 2D shooter and it felt a lot like SDL. In other words, mostly all commands were straightforward and high-level. Didn't feel overkill for me. In fact, if you already know C++ and have used a basic graphics library it's not too hard to jump into XNA (for 2D stuff at least).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544903/i-want-to-learn-game-development-which-language-should-i-use) to first decide the language that best suits the kind of game(s) that you wish to build. The IDE choice to follow.

Answer (score 7):

Considering what kind of game you want to create and what your problems are, I'd rather say that the game is poorly written, which might be your problem, not the language.

Comment: +1, Language can aid you to do tasks such as nice designer/available libraries. But this is only a help, your design is the nightmare not the IDE.

Comment: Well, how would you guys have done a board game? I'm not a professional programmer, just a student, so I did it the way I thought would be easiest - buttons, with a 2D array serving as container for the actual pieces.

Also, where I come from, not everyone has a 3.6 Ghz multi-core processor. Some of us here (and some institutions, like schools) are stuck with single core processors in the 1.6++ Ghz range.

Comment: @zack - Unless you code your application to support multiple threads, it would only have one main thread, and wouldn't take advantage of multiple cores anyways.  Your going to run into the same problems with Java, as your running into now, because of poor design.

Comment: Games like TicTacToe made using buttons on Delphi years ago were working *flawlessly* on 486 66MHz. Do you really felt some kind of slowness or are you just anticipating it? In the latter case first check it out...

Comment: @Asparagus, Students ask dumb questions and so they learn, saying he's crap is not going to help even if it may be true.

Comment: This answer is so pedantic and useless that I would give away 1000 points of my reputation for being able to down-vote it more than once.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in game development on .Net, perhaps this api can help you.  It is written in VB.Net, but you might find it instructive.

[.Net Game API](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/8cb8d926-6f79-41d2-a906-edf1c1aab650/#afcc2a0e-30c0-4034-973a-f83c27a9655d)

Answer (score 1):

Windows forms use GDI for graphics, while XNA uses hardware acceleration. There shouldn't be any performance concerns with using XNA to make a 2D board game. How efficiently it runs depends on how well you know the APIs for your language.